# How to replace the first occurrence of a character with a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a string which contains characters that should be replaced once (at first appearance).

These characters are:

- **L** => will be replaced with the lecture name
- **N** => will be replaced with a name
- **D** => will be replaced with a date

**Example input:**

```
L_N_L_D
```

**Desired result** (note that only the first `L` is replaced):

```
Math_Ex01_L_2018-10-05
```

**My current code** (simplified for the example):

```
let res = file_string.replace(/L|N|D/, x => {
  switch (x) {
    case 'L': return lecture;
    case 'N': return name;
    case 'D': return date;
    default: return x;
  }
});
```

What I get is this:

```
Math_L_N_D
```

If I change the regex to `/L|N|D/g` the second `L` will also be replaced which is not what I want.

How could this be implemented?

Comment: `let res = file_string.replace('D', date).replace('N', name).replace('L', lecture)` - note the order

Comment: I also tried this, but if the lecture contains the character 'N' for example the 'N' of the lecture will be replaced instead of the one in the file_string.

Comment: not if you do it in the order I did it ... *note the order*

Comment: The order is not fixed in my case, it can be dynamically changed by the user with a textfield. So if the name contains L I have the same problem as in the second comment.

Comment: oh ... OK ... thought it was fixed order :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your replacements in a map, once a replacement is made, set `map[x]` to `x`:

```js
let lecture = "Math";
let name = "Ex01";
let date = "2018-10-05";

let repl = {
  'L': lecture,
  'N': name,
  'D': date
};

let file_string = "L_N_L_D"

let result = file_string.replace(/[LND]/g, x => {
  let r = repl[x];
  repl[x] = x;
  return r;
});

console.log(result)
```

Apart from solving the problem at hand, this also greatly simplifies your replacement function (think adding new placeholders, for example).

That being said, a real solution to your problem would be to follow the @marsze's advice and use unambiguous placeholders, like `{...}`, in which case the whole enterprise becomes simply

```
 repl = {...as before...}
 result = subject.replace(/{(.+?)}/g, (_, x) => repl[x])
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering your general question "replace only the first occurrence of a character", you could do it like this:

```js
var lecture = "Math";
var name = "Ex01";
var date = "2018-10-05";
var found = {};
var file_string = "L_N_L_D";
var filename_result = file_string.split("").map(function (character) {
  if (!found[character]) {
    found[character] = true;
    switch (character) {
      case "L": return lecture;
      case "N": return name;
      case "D": return date;
    }
  }
  return character;
}).join("");
console.log(filename_result);
```

You should probably explain where that odd format of the `file_string` comes from. Are there other similar use cases? Or is this just about this specific example? Understanding the original requirements would help a lot.

If the `file_string` is supposed to be a configurable format string, then it should be improved. A sequence which serves as a placeholder to be replaced should (or **must**) be different from a literal, e.g.:

```
var filename_format = "{L}_{N}_L_{D}";
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected :D Great answer and fast ^^